# keep latest 4 versions of the file and delete the remaining versions

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am doing a cleanup script for a directory using KornShell (ksh).
I am keeping the file name prefixes in a text file. In ksh I want to read the prefix from the file, and match the pattern of the file and keep and compress(.Z) the latest four versions of the matched files in the directory. And I want to delete the remaining versions. Reason I am doing like this as the files are cumulative, I want to keep only the latest files only.

My text file has prefixes like this:

- abcd
- xyz
- pqr

My directory has many files with different names like this

- abcd###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.txt
- abcd###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.txt
- abcd###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.txt  (like this with different time stamps)
- xyz###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.dat
- xyz###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.dat
- xyz###.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.dat
- str12.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.txt
- qwefd.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.dat

In this directory, as I have prefixes abcd, xyz in the text file, so I want to compress the latest 4 versions of the files with that prefix and delete the remaining versions with that prefix. I do not want to touch the files not mentioned in the text file.
And I want to run the script next time I want similarly keep the latest file versions and remove the remaining versions (As next next time there are previously compressed files will be there.)  At any time I need only 4 latest file versions only. I can remove the previously compressed files.

I need a ksh script for this and any help is appreciable.

Comment: Why don't you use `logrotate` for this?

Comment: I want the matching pattern as the file names mentioned above..file extensions also matters for me..'

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use `logrotate` for this instead of reinventing the wheel as a dirty hack.

That said, here's a dirty hack that might work for you:

```
n=2
c=0
ls -r prefix* | while read f; do
    c=$((c+=1))
    if test $c -gt $n; then
        compress "$f"
    else
        rm -f "$f"
    fi
done
```

To match the date portion of the filename more accurate you could do this:

```
ls -r prefix.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.{txt,dat} 2>/dev/null
```

Or if `extglob` is enabled with `shopt` then this would be similar, though less strict:

```
ls -r prefix.+([0-9]).{txt,dat} 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: My problem is ...I want to match properly with the file patern as mentioned in my question ....example like prefix*.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.txt because I've prefix*.YYYYMMDDXXXXXX.dat also available. How to match?

Comment: @user2496132 I added a bit more info for that